# Generating a Short-and-Fat Random Orthonormal Matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy, linear-algebra

To generate a tall and thin orthonormal matrix (M>N) you simply:

```
a = np.random.random(size=(M, N))
q = scipy.linalg.orth(a)
```

Now `q.shape == (M,N)` and `matmul(transpose(q),q)==I`.

But this doesn't work when M is smaller than N.

Comment: How could the columns be orthonormal if they can't even be linearly independent?

Comment: You are right...!

Comment: Generate a tall thin matrix with orthogonal columns (ie U'*U=I) and take it's transpose; you get a short fat matrix with orthogonal rows (ie V*V' = I)

Comment: That doesn't work, you don't have both conditions of U'U=I and UU'=I, just one.

Comment: I tried to find an exact solution with M=3; N=2, and Mathematica cannot solve these equations. This is not possible.

Comment: @user1581390 you can only have U'U=I and UU'=I if U is square